What is the statistical opportunity of wrongly getting results of bulk email deliveries – whether emails were open or not?
In PostMark docs there's a sentence:

...there may be scenarios where an open event is not recorded even
when the recipient opened the message in their email client, or vice
versa where you see an open event in Postmark but the recipient
reports that they never opened the message.

"There may be scenarios" - what is the opportunity of this "may be"? Could it be presented in percentages? This percentage can only be approximate and depends on factors.

Details.
I ask this because I want to know if there is a sense in removing the recipients who never open emails, from Marketing bulk email lists. I can't be 100% sure they don't open since there is an opportunity for a mistake.
For instance, I send promotional bulk emails weekly and see that a recipient hasn't opened them for 6 months. If I remove that recipient but in fact he was opening, it just was not recorded, we lose a potential client.
For me, if the opportunity of ungetting Open events is below 3%, then there is a sense in cleaning idle recipients, however, if the general chance of such failure is 20%+, and we often can't be sure if the recipient opens or not, there's no sense in bothering with those for me.
After researching on the internet and asking PostMark Support, I can share I already know that in general, it's a good practice to some degree, to remove idle recipients. For the marketing audience, if they never click a link and never buy anything, they likely do not open the emails. If my audience is more technical, it’s more likely that Open Events were hidden. If the audience is less technical, it’s less likely.
This question is not about delivery failures, bounces, invalid addresses, etc. This is only about successfully delivered emails.

This url, https://www.litmus.com/blog/gmail-data-analysis-reveals-image-blocking-affects-43-of-emails, has a study on which email clients block images by default. You number is probably close to that, as that is how email opens are usually reported, with an image pixel being loaded.
